# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, classcastexception, swiperefreshlayout

Maybe you will see couple same questions but those didn't help me to solve this.

My XML contains `RecyclerView` inside `SwipeRefreshLayout`. When I run my code, it throws below exception or app crashes.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
>   cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout

My XML :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rlList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rlSearch"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rlBottomCreateIncident"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_Incidents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_Incidents"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Java Code inside Activity :

```
private void initializeUI() {

    //Initialize swipe to refresh view
    mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Incidents);
    mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //Refreshing data on server
        }
    });

    mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents.setRefreshing(true);

    recyclerViewIncidents = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Incidents);
    sp_incidentAdapter = new SP_IncidentAdapter(context, sp_incidentListItemArrayList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerViewIncidents.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerViewIncidents.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewIncidents.setAdapter(sp_incidentAdapter);
    recyclerViewIncidents.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(context,
            new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // TODO Handle item click
                    Log.v("item click", " working fine");
                }
            })
    );
}
```

Comment: where you call initializeUI()???

Comment: Change `R.id.recyclerView_Incidents` to `R.id.swipeRefreshLayout_Incidents` for `SwipeRefreshLayout`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Holy crap!!! What a silliy mistake I made. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: Side note: we like questions that are succinct and to the point here. There is no need to add [please-help begging](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4390557+please+help) to all of your questions. It does not make answers faster or more likely - just gives editors more work to do.

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong view id for `mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents`, use `R.id.swipeRefreshLayout_Incidents` instead.

Answer (score 3):

That error means that you are casting `RecyclerView` to `SwipeRefreshLayout`:. Instead of this:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_Incidents);
```

use this:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayoutIncidents = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout_Incidents);
```

What i am done is changing `recyclerView_Incidents` with `swipeRefreshLayout_Incidents`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Under `recyclerView_Incidents` you have a `RecyclerView` (which does not inherit from `SwipeRefreshLayout`, as said in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), hence the exception). Use id `swipeRefreshLayout_Incidents` in the very first line of your method instead - I think that was your intention in the first place.